# RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox for other users

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

Using Exchange 2016 on premises, I'm trying to logon to another users mailbox from my admin account using the RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox method. The admin account has impersonation access to all other mailboxes so should have rights to do this. After running the logon method the RDOSession object shows ExchangeConnectionMode as olCachedConnectedFull, but the RDOSession.CurrentUser.name shows as UNKNOWN. If I try to access the inbox using  GetDefaultFolder I get a MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED message. Can you suggest what I might be doing wrong, or haven't done to allow this ?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code used to connect to another mailbox- what parameters are passed and etc.

Answer (score 0):

`LogonExchangeMailbox` always uses the identity of the current user to connect to the mailbox in the RPC mode (no longer supported by Exchange 2016). To open another mailbox, you can call `RDOSession.GetSharedMailBox` / `GetSharedMailBoxEx`.

You can also use `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` - it takes explicit credentials instead of connecting as the current local user.